# Looking for source code for Hibernate-core 3.5.1-Final

Tags: hibernate

I am looking for hibernate-core 3.5.1-Final source code. I am not able to find it in the GitHub or http://hibernate.org/orm/

Any lead will be helpful.

Thanks.